# Is there a key combination similiar to windows to restart computer?

Tags: restart, function-keys

I used to be a Windows user, and when my computer froze I could press CTRL+ALT+Delete and it would restart the computer. Is there a similar function for my current operating system? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd> (Hold down Ctrl, Alt, and Prnt Scrn then press REISUB in that order with about a second pause between each letter)

This is a functionality that is a part of the Linux kernel (not just Ubuntu). The only catch is that you have to have the keyboard plugged into the computer (doesn't work remotely).

Answer (score 1):

Press the power button on your keyboard. The system will allow you to select the icon that looks like a power button to turn off the computer. There's a circular arrow that will let you reboot it without powering it down, coming the closest to Windows `CTRL`-`ALT`-`DELETE`.

dash-plus-java's helpful suggestion is good in emergencies when this won't work, but it doesn't allow the various daemon's in your system to terminate normally. (That's not normally a disaster, though).

Answer (score 1):

@dash-plus-java answered correctly, but not all SysRq keys are enabled by default. Out of the `REISUB` only `U` and `B` are enabled. If you want to enable all SysRqs, do:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

This will enable *all* sysrqs. If you want just some of them, change the value you echo above, as mentioned in the kernel Docs, https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt

Now you can press and hold `<Alt> <Sys Rq>`, and sequentially press `R`, `E`, `I`, `S`, `U` and `B`. Each of them have specific meaning:

- r - Puts the keyboard into raw mode, taking control of it away from the X server.
- e - Sends the terminate signal to all processes, asking them to end gracefully.
- i - Sends the kill signal to all processes, forcing them to end immediately.
- s - Flushes data from your cache to disk.
- u - Remounts all file systems read-only.
- b - Reboots your computer.

More SysRqs:

- n - Resets the nice level (priority) of all high and realtime priority processes.
- f - Calls oom_kill, which will kill a memory-hogging process.
- k - k – Kills all programs on the current virtual console, including X
- o - Shuts off the computer.